# creating more than 10 google map api key (V2)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

does anyone know how to generate more than 10 keys for google map api version 2 ? i am trying to generate them at: https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and  it keeps giving a "an error has occurred , please try again later" . googling the error was not very helpful either.

Infact, to tell the truth, i have not even found any such restriction that creating more than 10 keys is not allowed .

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Why do you need more than 1 key?

Answer (score 0):

The Map API V2 required a key for each domain allowed to access the maps.
The V3 API you create a single key locked to you Google account and then make a white-list of allowed domains.
As the V2 was deprecated back in 2010 you probably can't make any new keys for that.